# interpolation syntax nested array of objects doesn't show anything (Angular 10)

Tags: angular

I hope you're fine.
My problem is showing the received data from an API but wait... I have the data but actually, the challenging part for me is the nested array of objects that I can't show the data in my template by interpolation syntax.
these are my code snippets

```
{
"id": "5FCD517F-9820-4FD4-90DF-CCD473524199",
"Title": "blah blah blah",
"description": "Question Groups",
"IsActive": true,
"answerTypeId": "C2D9A992-8701-437C-8FB3-3DA7269A728F",
"answerType": {
    "Id": "C2D9A992-8701-437C-8FB3-3DA7269A728F",
    "Title": "Evaluation",
    "code": 22,
    "description": "it's me Sia",
    "IsActive": false,
    "Row": 2,
    "AnswerTypeOption": [{
        "id": "dd",
        "description": "Yes/No",
        "rate": 2,
        "questionOrder": 54,
        "isActive": true
    }]
}
```

}

I need to get a JSON like this, I logged in my console log and get the same data.
As you see the inner object is a list which the one I couldn't show in my template.
I looped through this data but can't access to the inner list which is AnswerTypeOptions but the rest of this is OK.

this is my HTML code

```
<mat-card class="align" *ngFor="let question of questionList">

            <mat-card-content>
                <div class="row between-xs">
                    <div class="col-xs-10 start-xs">
                        <p>
                            {{question.title + '-'}}
                            {{question.description}}
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-2 end-xs">
                        <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="onRemoveQuestion()">
                            <mat-icon [inline]="false">delete</mat-icon>
                        </button>

                        <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="onEditQuestion($event)">
                            <mat-icon [inline]="false">edit</mat-icon>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row between-xs answers">
                    <div class="col-md-11">
                        <div class="row bottom-md">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2" *ngFor="let item of question.answerType.answerTypeOption">
                                {{item.description}}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </mat-card-content>

        </mat-card>
```

the first ngFor is OK and works fine but the second one neither shows anything nor throw an error!!
I'd appreciate if anyone can help me.

and this is my logged data in the console log

[image]

Comment: shouldn't be answerTypeOption's' ?

Comment: In your JSON object like you shared in question the keys `**answerType**` and `**AnswerTypeOptions**` both has stars `**` at beginning and at end? If yes then thats the issue try remove stars from key name its invalid.

Comment: No , that is just the sample JSON @Khodayar J

Comment: @Kamran Khatti No, sorry about that, I edited the JSON sample

Comment: @siavashbashiri looks like few of your JSON field names differ from what you used in your template I have tweaked your code checkout working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-stxkee

Comment: Yes, that was the difference between answerTypeOptions property names within models come from back-end and the front-end.  A big bad mistake. Tnx @Kamran Khatti

Comment: @siavashbashiri you have inconsistent field names in your JSON object and in interface images you posted, however I have updated my stackblitz example to address your issue check it out https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-stxkee and also have a deep look at field names.

Comment: Yes, it works now, thank you for your help Kaman